# How to use subprocess or other method to call lrzsz command?

Tags: python, anonymous-pipes

How can I use subprocess or other methods to call a lrzsz command? I do this because of there is only-serial-port support. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def main():
    conn = connect("172.31.10.8")
    cmd = "sz -Xbe 1.pcap"
    stdin, stdout,stderr = conn.exec_command(cmd) 
    subproc = subprocess.Popen("rz.exe -Xbe",stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    subproc.communicate(stdout.read())
```

Comment: Why the C - tag?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have supplied? Does it not work? How so?

Comment: yes it doesnt work. Now my solution is make another subprocess to execute cmd, and contact the rz , sz with subprocess.PIPE.